# Keep configurations for DietJS server

Tags: node.js, diet-js

Rather than having to change the URL passed in `diet.listen()` method on every server that I deploy my application on, there should be a better way to maintain such parameters in the application.

What options do we have to be able to manage such parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a '.json' file there at the root of the application and then do a require for the same. For example:

```
var configuration = require('./config.json');
```

The example expects you to save a file named 'config.json' with all your configuration as a JSON. The `configuration` object will hold all your settings that you might want to make dynamic and read at runtime.

Comment: That seems a clean way to do that... At least I won't get conflicts while pulling the latest updated code on each server (until I change something in the default config).